# Is MetroCriteriaId an integer or a string?

Tags: google-ads-api, geo

The Google documentation for the [GeoPerformance report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports#geo) is a little confusing. On the one hand it says that `MetroCriteriaId` is of Type Integer but in the Notes it says `Name of the metro as a string.`

Do anyone know which one is correct, or do I just suck it and see?

Comment: Suck it down, check, and answer your own question. (It should be a very fast check)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to matter what it is, Int or String, as even in 80812-line report the field is empty. The report definition I used is below and I got data for everything except `MetroCriteriaId`. Dead field? No idea.

```
<reportDefinition xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201406">
<selector>
<fields>AccountCurrencyCode</fields>
<fields>AccountDescriptiveName</fields>
<fields>AccountTimeZoneId</fields>
<fields>AdFormat</fields>
<fields>AdGroupId</fields>
<fields>AdGroupName</fields>
<fields>AdGroupStatus</fields>
<fields>AdNetworkType1</fields>
<fields>AdNetworkType2</fields>
<fields>AverageCpc</fields>
<fields>AverageCpm</fields>
<fields>AveragePosition</fields>
<fields>CampaignId</fields>
<fields>CampaignName</fields>
<fields>CampaignStatus</fields>
<fields>CityCriteriaId</fields>
<fields>Clicks</fields>
<fields>Conversions</fields>
<fields>Cost</fields>
<fields>CostPerConversion</fields>
<fields>CostPerConversionManyPerClick</fields>
<fields>CountryCriteriaId</fields>
<fields>Ctr</fields>
<fields>CustomerDescriptiveName</fields>
<fields>Date</fields>
<fields>DayOfWeek</fields>
<fields>Device</fields>
<fields>ExternalCustomerId</fields>
<fields>Impressions</fields>
<fields>IsTargetingLocation</fields>
<fields>LocationType</fields>
<fields>MetroCriteriaId</fields>
<fields>Month</fields>
<fields>MonthOfYear</fields>
<fields>MostSpecificCriteriaId</fields>
<fields>PrimaryCompanyName</fields>
<fields>Quarter</fields>
<fields>RegionCriteriaId</fields>
<fields>ValuePerConversion</fields>
<fields>ValuePerConversionManyPerClick</fields>
<fields>ViewThroughConversions</fields>
<fields>Week</fields>
<fields>Year</fields>
<dateRange>
<min>20140601</min>
<max>20140630</max>
</dateRange></selector>
<reportName>Custom Geo Performance Report</reportName>
<reportType>GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT</reportType>
<dateRangeType>CUSTOM_DATE</dateRangeType>
<downloadFormat>TSV</downloadFormat>
</reportDefinition>
```